# Recommended way of getting data from the server

Tags: angularjs

What is the recommended way to connect to server data sources in AngularJS without using `$resource`.

The `$resource` has many limitations such as:

1. Not using proper futures
2. Not being flexible enough

Comment: Is it still true that $resource has the limitation of not using proper futures given that this issue [(https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/415)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/415) has been closed?  (I'm new to Angular, my apologies if the question is confusing.) EDIT - This commit (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/dba6bc73e802fdae685a9f351d3e23c7efa8568a) also seems to suggest that $resource may not have that limitation anymore?

Comment: well it's legal in here to answer your own questions ..ok? press "Ask Question", that's called "share your knowledge"

Answer (score 230):

There are cases when $resource may not be appropriate when talking to backend. This shows how to set up $resource like behavior without using resource.

```js
angular.module('myApp').factory('Book', function($http) {
  // Book is a class which we can use for retrieving and 
  // updating data on the server
  var Book = function(data) {
    angular.extend(this, data);
  }

  // a static method to retrieve Book by ID
  Book.get = function(id) {
    return $http.get('/Book/' + id).then(function(response) {
      return new Book(response.data);
    });
  };

  // an instance method to create a new Book
  Book.prototype.create = function() {
    var book = this;
    return $http.post('/Book/', book).then(function(response) {
      book.id = response.data.id;
      return book;
    });
  }

  return Book;
});
```

Then inside your controller you can:

```js
var AppController = function(Book) {
  // to create a Book
  var book = new Book();
  book.name = 'AngularJS in nutshell';
  book.create();

  // to retrieve a book
  var bookPromise = Book.get(123);
  bookPromise.then(function(b) {
    book = b;
  });
};
```

Comment: Maybe a noob question but how would one extend this to allow for a get() that returned multiple responses not just a single response?

Comment: @NathanBunney, you could have your static get method above loop through the results and build an array of Books.

Comment: @NathanBunney ' Book.getAll = function() {
    return $http.get('/Book').then(function(response) { var books = []; for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){books.push(new Book(response.data[i]));}
      return books;
    });
  };'

Comment: why do i get `Unknown provider: BookProvider <- Book` Error ??

Comment: How would you share a `book` or collection of `book`s between controllers?

Comment: @MiskoHevery Why does Book.get() call to the server only once and then when called again from the controller - it doesn't poll the server any more? I want to use it in the $timeout and have that issue...

Comment: In the controller I had to remove `new Book()` and just make it `var book = Book`. I'm not well versed enough in JS to say why.

Comment: can anybody explain me what is the purpose of  return new Book(response.data); instead of return response.data;

Comment: You seem to assume that your $http.get cannot fail?

Comment: @harikrish The idea is to return an object that has methods you can call on it like "update"; which wasn't shown, I assume for brevity.  You can see how "update" can be implemented by looking at "create".

Comment: This is great (obviously since Misko created the framework), but I'm struggling to figure out how to make it reusable. If I wanted to implement the CRUD functions only once and then inherit their functionality in child factories/services that needed only a urlBase argument (preferably stored on the prototype so that each instance didn't need a new copy of the urlBase), how would I do that?

Answer (score 26):

I recommend that you use [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).

It may support (url override) in next version of Angularjs.
Then you will be able to code like this:

```
// need to register as a serviceName
$resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'}, {
    'customActionName':    {
        url:'/user/someURI'
        method:'GET',
        params: {
            param1: '....',
            param2: '....',
        }
    },
     ....
});
```

And return callbacks can be handled in ctrl scope like this.

```
// ctrl scope
serviceName.customActionName ({
    paramName:'param',
    ...
}, 
function (resp) {
    //handle return callback
}, 
function (error) {
    //handler error callback
});
```

Probably you can handle code on higher abstraction level.

Comment: Current version of angular.js supports url override in $resource module.

Comment: Haha you are recommending the actual creator of the framework on how to do something :P

Comment: OMG! I feel so ashamed.