# Why is the POST request response data null in CasperJS even though same request shows data in Postman

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

How do I resolve CasperJS script for POST request issue? Get response data is null, even though same request show data in POSTMAN, with exact same request.

```
casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose         : true
    clientScripts   : ['includes/jquery-2.1.1.min.js']
});

casper.start();

var productId = casper.cli.get("productId");
var pageNum = casper.cli.get("pageNum");
var url = 'https://example.com/store/getreviews?authuser=0';

var data= {
 a:'val1',    
 b:'val2'
```

};

```
casper.thenOpen(
    url,
    {
        method: 'POST',
        data: data
    }
);

casper.then(function(response) {
    this.echo('Response: '+JSON.stringify(response,null,2));
    this.capture('this.png');
});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run using this command :  casperjs --ssl-protocol=any example.js

```
 var casper = require('casper').create({
        verbose : true,
        logLevel :"debug"
    });

    casper.start();

    casper.then(function() {
        this.open('http://example.com/');
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        resp = this.evaluate(function() {
            var res = $.ajax({
                url: 'https://example.com/store/getreviews?authuser=0',
                method: 'POST',
                data: { 
                    a=val1,
                    b=val2
                },
                async: false
            });
            return res.responseText;
        });
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        console.log(resp);
    });

    casper.run();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the POST request response data null in CasperJS

PhantomJS doesn't provide the contents of any request or response. You can only read the header information, the status code and the content length. You can access the request/response body in [Slimer.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32643652/1816580) though.

> How do I resolve CasperJS script for POST request issue?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24561614/1816580) are some workarounds.

Comment: in casper js , possible to get jsonp data ,  I get info from casper js using GET ,  I try to get content using POST request ,

Comment: Now how to get Jsonp data from casperjs POST request

Comment: even in POSTMAN it work fine and show me data in format                             [  
  [  1                                                                                                                                                "ecr"   <some html>                                          </some html>                              2 ] ]

Comment: csrf issue , if your post request work fine in postman then probably issue in csrf token ,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823524/how-to-create-a-post-request-including-csrf-token-using-django-and-angularjs