# Angular trailing slash for resource

Tags: angularjs

My api requires a trailing slash for api calls.  I was wondering how to pull that off with angular.

So i need to be able to access `/tasks/` or a `/tasks/xxxx/.`  I attempted to do it via:

```
angular.module('taskServices', ['ngResource']).
        factory('Tasks', function($resource){
            return $resource('/tasks/:task_id/', {}, {
                 query: {method:'GET', 
                         params:{},
                         isArray:true}
            });
 });
```

and a

```
$scope.tasks = Tasks.query();
```

But it results in a `/tasks` or a `tasks/xxx` query.

How can i force it to always be `/tasks/` and `/tasks/xxx/`

Comment: it might be a bug , i dont see why angular would force teh trailing slash to be removed

Comment: You can also add a # at the end of the url but there might be some unknown consequences.

Comment: @Breedly i just switch... thanks for helping me keep this up to date.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5560

You can now configure it this way:

```
app.config(function($resourceProvider) {
  $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the heads up.

Comment: getting the error as

TypeError: Cannot set property 'stripTrailingSlashes' of undefined

Comment: Note that you don't have to add this to your app it can be added to your resources module as well: `angular.module('myresources',['ngResource'])
.config(function($resourceProvider) {
    $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
})`

Answer (score 35):

The trailing slash is explicitly removed in [this line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/69be39fccfceae13c4850e1dcf097fcd7d9ce395/src/ngResource/resource.js#L329) of AngularJS source code. I'm not fully sure what was the rationale behind this code but there is already an issue opened for this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/992

As noted in the mentioned issue the `$resource` factory is great for RESTful endpoints that conform to a certain specification. While `$resource` will do do great job talking to back-ends conforming to a this specification, it has limitations that might rule it out for back-ends that don't obey a contract expected by the `$resource`. In such a case the best way forward is to switch to using the lower-level `$http` service as noted in this question: [Recommended way of getting data from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11850025/1418796)

`$http` is a very powerful and flexible service and allows full control over URLs, parameters sent etc.

Comment: escaping the trailing slash ( 'foo/:id\\/' ) works for me ( v1.1.3 )

Comment: @vincent Sounds like that might break if they fix the bug in Angular

Comment: but firefox transform the escaping slash to %5C ... it's really annoying

Answer (score 20):

adding a space at the very end of the url template works here (tested with angular 1.2.0):

```
{url: '/user/:id/ '}
```

Comment: Be careful here. If this would be used for GET with some params in your query string it will fail!

Answer (score 6):

Adding the 2 back-slashes to escape the trailing slash on the URL worked for me on Chrome and Safari.

Firefox however decides that its a good idea to remove the trailing slash from the URL and encode the backslash that was escaping the forward slash to %5C...great :-)  So in the example above you'd get http://example.com/controller/save%5C, which then 404s at the server.

I'm using Django+TastyPie for my project and need the trailing slash on the URL, I'll be looking to modify ngResource rather than dropping down to $http for everything as the lowest common denominator.

Comment: Have you got any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

For AngularJS clients that use [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), just use [angular-django-rest-resource](https://github.com/blacklocus/angular-django-rest-resource). Worked great.

Answer (score 1):

One can use http interceptors for all or specific urls, e.g. api urls:

```
app.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q) {
    return {
        'request': function(config) {
            if (config.url.indexOf('/api/') != -1 && config.url.slice(-1) != '/') {
                config.url += '/';
            }
            return config || $q.when(config);
        }
    };
});

app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around for this until/if they ever change the AngularJS source, I set a .htaccess rewrite rule to add a trailing slash to all incoming requests to the webserver.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Downsides of this approach:

- Network traffic of RESTful calls get 301 redirected, so you see requests being sent twice
- This works only for GET requests (note the restriction in my example), if the rewrite receives POST, DELETE, PUT requests and redirects, it does so as a GET request of the same URL, which may not be what you want of course, since you lose your payload.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get over the Firefox encoding issue by adding this to the ngResource before composing the final url:

```
url = url.replace(/\\/,"/");
```

This allows the slash escape fix for Chrome/Safari to work well on Firefox.

```
app.factory('Things', function($resource){
        return $resource('/api/v1/thing\\/', {}, {
              query: {method:'GET', params:{},isArray:true}});
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

Vincent's escaping of the trailing slash (add two backslashes and a forward slash (http://example.com/controller/save\\/) to the end of the URL) worked for me.