# angular 1.1.5 and trailing slash

Tags: django, angularjs, angularjs-resource

i am using django + angularjs + ng-resource to build my resources. the problem of angular removing trailing slashes has been discussed, and i have tried every solution.

this is my current code.

```
app.factory('Thread', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        '/api/thread/:id\\/', {
            id: '@id'
        }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        }
    );
});
```

but when i call the $save method on Thread, this is my debug server logs this

```
[24/Jul/2013 15:33:39] "POST /api/thread// HTTP/1.1" 404 7341
```

two slashes. how can i get it have only one slash.

Comment: Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533117/angular-trailing-slash-for-resource I think at some point you should switch to `$http` too

Comment: Is id undefined or null?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat yes, id is undefined when i call $save

Comment: @HieuNguyen .. i went through that thread before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the forward slash before the :id?