# Misunderstanding of Single-Page Routing in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, single-page-application

I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding about the way angular intercepts my routes in a single-page application.

My problem, I think, is pretty simple. When I enter the url:

```
localhost:3000/streams/
```

I would like to load the 'streams' page. The way I thought it works is as follows:

1. My express server receives the request, and answers with a layout.

   ```
   app.get('/streams/',function(req,res){
    res.render('layout');
   })
   ```
2. My layout page is rendered. It calls a client app.js and has ng-view.
3. Angular intercepts the '/streams/' path, and then makes a call for the 'streams' template. Like this:

   ```
    $routeProvider
     .when('/',
      {
       templateUrl: '/templates/mainpage'
      }
     )
     .when('/streams/',
      {
       templateUrl: '/templates/streams'
      }
     )
   ```

For some reason, reality is very very different.

When I load `'/streams'`, angular retrieves `/templates/streams`, and

when I load `'/streams/`, angular retrieves `/templates/mainpage`.

Why?

---

This misunderstanding has been trolling me for days now...

Any help will be rewarded with 5 quanta of good energy.

Thanks.

Comment: It's because /streams/ doesn't match any of your defined routes, and you have no default set. It probably just grabs the first .when() defined which is /templates/mainpage.

Comment: Thanks. What I don't understand, @ZackArgyle is why /streams/ doesn't match my defined routes. Isn't it taken care of by the second .when() statement?

Comment: Yeah, that is a "feature" of angular. Check out this question [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533117/angular-trailing-slash-for-resource)

Comment: I think I understand. So basically my best bet would be to try to use $http calls inside my .when() statements and not rely on angular's $resource?

Comment: It looks like you should try escaping the last it like this, '/streams\\/' or adding a space at the end like this '/streams/ '. I haven't tried them but its worth trying before resorting to $http for everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the real issue was a little different.

It's not, as was described, that Angular didn't know that I'm referring to 'streams', when I load 'streams/', it's that html had a relative base.

Basically, this relative base made it seem as though I have already found a template, namely, '/streams', and am now retrieving another one, namely, '/'. This issue can be simply resolved by adding the root base in your html.

```
 <base href="/">
```

This should do it.