# karma controller not loading scope

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

So I am learning how to use karma. And I have read several tutorials on how to inject scope into my project, but I am still getting errors on

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope
>     http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope

Here is my spec:

```
describe('InfoController', function() {
  var InfoController, state;  
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ptoApp.controller'));
  var $controller
  var scope;
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$scope, $state,$rootScope, employeeTestFactory) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    InfoController = $controller('InfoController', {
      $scope: scope,
      state: $state,
      employeeTestFactory: employeeTestFactory
    });
  }));

  // Verify our controller exists
  it('should be defined', function() {
    expect(InfoController).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

And here is my controller:

```
.controller('InfoController', ['$scope', '$state','$rootScope', 'employeeTestFactory', function ($scope, $state, $rootScope, employeeTestFactory) {
        $scope.loggedIn = {}; 
        $scope.displaySection = true;
        $rootScope.callInfo=function(){
            employeeTestFactory.get($rootScope.email).then(function(result) {
                $scope.loggedIn = result;
            });
        }
        $scope.getPercentUsed = function(){
            if(typeof $rootScope.employee === 'undefined' || typeof $rootScope.employee.totalTimeUsed === 'undefined' || typeof $rootScope.employee.totalTimeAccrued === 'undefined') return 0;
            var percentage = ($rootScope.employee.totalTimeUsed/$rootScope.employee.totalTimeAccrued)*100;
            return (percentage > 100) ?  100 : percentage;
        }
        $scope.hideSession = function(){
            $scope.displaySection = !$scope.displaySection;
        }
    }])
```

Now I have heard for scope, it is useful to attach a new rootScope to it right away, so I added scope = $rootScope.$new(); and then set it to $scope: scope, when creating the controller. Still getting the error.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your karma spec file, remove `$scope` from your `inject` function params:

```
- beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$scope, $state,$rootScope, employeeTestFactory) {
+ beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $state, $rootScope, employeeTestFactory) {
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Do you have any information or tutorials on how to inject factories? A lot of my controllers call to a factory to get the data, then use that day in the controller. Would like to know how to mock that up the right way. I found one tut, but it was for services, might try it the same way, not sure if it will work for factories.

Comment: Great! There is a good post on mocking dependencies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554727/mocking-angular-module-dependencies-in-jasmine-unit-tests#18228805