# How to mock a module API dependency in Jasmine unit test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, dependency-injection, jasmine

I have a case to unit test a custom Angular directive `myApp` and have set up the necessary karma and jasmine config.
In this test case I've tried to mock and stub the dependency module of `myApp`, which is the service - `services.FuzzAPI`.
As I don't have access to the services.FuzzAPI file to mock it using sinon.

Following the Angular and Jasmine docs I setup up my spec file in the `.spec` file and following this [similar SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18228805/1829251)

1. In first beforeEach created a mock of the depedency accroding to [this guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/mocking-dependencies-angularjs-tests/)
   and registered the `myApp` modules to test using `angular.mock.module`.
2. Then in the second beforeEach used the $injector to pass that mocked FuzzAPI for $compile step of `myApp` directive.

But even after mocking the dependency I get an `$injector:modulerr` telling me that the services.FuzzAPI is not available.
Which tells me soemthing is a miss with the registration of the `services.FuzzAPI` dependency:

```
 LOG LOG: 'before mock'
 LOG LOG: 'after mock'
 Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
        Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module services.FuzzAPI due to:
        Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'services.FuzzAPI' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it
```

**Question:**

How can you mock a directive depedency in a Jasmine unit test?

Looking at the code I can see that this error is being thrown on line `beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$compile_, $injector) {`
as the console.log inside the inject `beforeEach` isn't tirggered before the error is thrown.

*Gist of directive and test spec:*

// my-app.js

```
(function() {

  var component = {
    id: "myApp",
    name: "My App",
    templateUrl: localStorage.getItem("baseURL") + "my-app/my-app.html"
  };

  component.ui = angular.module("myApp", ["services.FuzzAPI"]);
  component.ui.directive("myApp", widgetComponent);

  function widgetComponent(FuzzAPI) {

    // main widget container
    function widgetContainer(scope, element, params) {
      var api = new FuzzAPI(params);

      scope.greeting = "Hello World";

      var setGreeting = function(message){
        scope.greeting = message;  
      };

      api.onDataEvent("onFuzzEvent", function(data) {
        scope.greeting = data;
      });


      element.on("$destroy", function() {     
        api.unregister();
        scope.$destroy();
      });
    }

    return {
      scope: {},
      replace: true,
      link: widgetContainer,
      templateUrl: component.templateUrl
    };
  }
})();
```

//my-app.spec.js

```
describe("myApp", function() {

  var $scope, $compile, $provide, $injector, element, fuzzAPIMock, FuzzAPIProvider;

  beforeEach(function(){

    //mock service FuzzAPI via service provider
    fuzzAPIMock = {
      greeting : "123",
      initializeCurrentItem : function () {
        return true;
      }
    };

    console.log("before mock");

    //register module and mock dependency
    angular.mock.module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('services.FuzzAPI', fuzzAPIMock);
    });

    angular.mock.module("myApp");

    console.log("after mock");


  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$compile_, $injector) {

    console.log("in inject..");
    FuzzAPIProvider = $injector.get('services.FuzzAPI');
    $scope = $rootScope.$new(), //create instance of rootScope
    $compile = _$compile_; 
    console.log("in inject before compile..");
    element = $compile("<my-app></my-app>")($scope); // compile attaches directives to HTML template
    console.log("in inject after compile..");
    $scope.$digest(); //loop through DOM watchers, check values and trigger listeners
  }));


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'services.FuzzAPI' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it

means that it is `services.FuzzAPI` **module** that should be mocked, not **service**. According to provided code, service name is `FuzzAPI`, and it should be mocked with **constructor function**, not **object**.

In order for the missing module to not cause an error, it should be stubbed. It can be stubbed once, in top-level `describe` block:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  angular.module('services.FuzzAPI', []);
});
```

It's not possible to restore stubbed module (at least without a hack), but it's not a problem if real module shouldn't be presented in tests.

Then services can be mocked as usual. If it's `FuzzAPI`:, it should be

```
fuzzAPIMock = jasmine.createSpy('').and.returnValue({
  greeting : "123",
  initializeCurrentItem : jasmine.createSpy('').and.returnValue(true)
});

angular.mock.module(function($provide) {
  $provide.value('FuzzAPI', fuzzAPIMock);
});
```

It is always preferable to use Jasmine spies as mocked/stubbed functions.