# AngularJS Jasmine: mocking ngModule with dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

So in my project I'm using only one module everywhere.

Here is how it looks:

```
angular
    .module('moduleToMock', [
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngAria',
        'ngMessages',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngMaterial',
        'md.data.table',
        'textAngular',
        'ui.utils.masks',
        'mp.colorPicker',
        'mdPickers',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngIdle',
        'toastr',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ui.bootstrap.typeahead'
    ])
```

You see a bunch of services in require section.

Right now I'm going to start writing tests. The error I'm getting is `Module 'ngAnimate' is not available`. I already found [the same question discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554727/mocking-angular-module-dependencies-in-jasmine-unit-tests)

So as I see, I should go with something like this:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    module('moduleToMock');

    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('ngAnimate', module('ngAnimate', []));
        $provide.value('ngAria', module('ngAria', []));
        $provide.value('ngMessages', module('ngMessages', []));
        $provide.value('ngRoute', module('ngRoute', []));
        $provide.value('ngMaterial', module('ngMaterial', []));
        ...
    });
});
```

And this piece of code I have to insert in the beginning of each test of each service, factory, controller and etc.? Is there a way to do not copy-paste it each time I'm writing tests? Most of dependencies I have is not being injected into controllers, just declared as ngModule requirenment.