# How to test AngularJS when including external APIs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, soundcloud

I'm using the SoundCloud JavaScript SDK with AngularJS, and trying to run Karma tests on it. I keep getting the error `Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module SoundcloudApp due to: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: SC` when I run the tests.

The variable SC (provided by the SoundCloud API, when including the script) is used in an AngularJS service:

```
angular.module('SoundcloudApp').provider('SoundCloud', function() {
  SC.initialize({
    clientId: 'SeES8KzD8c44J9IU8djbVg'
  });

  this.$get = function($q) {
    return {
      getUser: function(id) {
        // returns user object with a given id

        var user = $q.defer(); 


        SC.get('/users/' + id, function (userData, err) {
          if (err) {
            user.reject(err.message);
          } else {
            user.resolve(userData);
          }
        });

        return user.promise;
      }
    };
  };
});
```

Should I just mock this service? How do I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to create a mock for `SC` or a mock for the actual `Soundcloud` service?

Comment: I want to mock the service, I suppose. I know how to do that by manually declaring a variable [as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24127144/1080586), but I'd prefer to keep the mocked service in a separate file and inject it somehow.

Comment: Just declare it on a module, e.g. `angular.module('myMocks', []).provider('SoundCloudMock', ...)` and make sure to include that file in your test config. Then use pretty much the same approach except inject the mocked service instead of creating it inline.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject mocks into your service by using $provide.

You can find an explanation in the answer to this question:
[Injecting a mock into an AngularJS service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773269/injecting-a-mock-into-an-angularjs-service)

Comment: Only problem with that is that SC isn't injected via DI in his code, it's assumed to be available as a global variable. Unless of course I misread the question and he wants to mock the actual service and not its dependency on SC.