# How to mock a service and inject it to another service?

Tags: angularjs, service, mocking

I have a service which is being tested:

```
angular.module('services', []).
  service('myService', function(topService) {});
```

And the `topService` is another angularjs service.

Now I want to write unit test for `myService`, but I need to mock the `topService` and pass it to myService.

I tried but not sure how to make it work:

```
define(['angular', 'angularMocks', 'services/my'], function(_, mocks, _) {

    beforeEach(mocks.module('services'));

    describe("my service", function() {

        it("should do something", mocks.inject(function(myService) {
            // how to mock and inject a `topService` to `myService` ????
            expect(myService).doSomething().toEqual("???");
        }));
    });
});
```

How to do that?

Comment: A very good answer for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18756347/342235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the mockedTopService, provide any function which will be needed by the test to run:

```
var mockedtopService = {
    doSomething: function() {
        return "test";
    }
};
```

Then provide it to angular using $provide:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('topService', mockedtopService );
    });
}
```

In case you need to get an instance of the service via angular you can do it this way:

```
inject(function (topService) {
    var topServiceInstance = topService;
});
```

Comment: in the module, shouldn't you return null so it doesn't mess up previously injected module?

Comment: How would it mess it up? Can you explain me more what you mean with your question, please?

Comment: Thank you. I tried similar solution, but I found the `topService` I mocked here, will make the tests in other files fail. Very strange.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, It happened to me that when I had module like the one in your answer after using `module('myWebApp')` it caused weird behaviour in tests, and when I did `return null` it get stable again. I mean your answer is correct for sure, I was just wondering if this behaviour is common or it was like that just for me

Comment: @Freewind then the tests are not good, they should be stateless and clearly from what you are saying they inherit from previous tests

Comment: @maurycy I see. It has never happened to me so I can't tell. Would be nice to see full code.

Comment: I found that I should put the `beforeEach(module(...))` inside the `describe(...)`. If I put them outside, it will impact other tests