# AngularJS jasmine factory tests with spy

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have an account and user factory. Now I want to test the account Factory.

In the test I want to check whether new User() was called and fake data is returned.

```
angular.module('app')

.factory 'Account', [ 'User', (User) ->
  class @Account
    constructor: (account) ->
      @self = this
      @user = new User(account.user_id)
]

.factory 'User', [ '$http', ($http) ->
  class @User
    constructor: (id)
      $http.get('/user.json?id='+id)
      .success (data) =>
        //do something
      .error (data) ->
        //do something
]
```

Test:

```
describe 'app', ->
  describe 'Account', ->
    Account   = undefined
    User      = undefined

    beforeEach(module('app'))

    beforeEach inject((_Account_, _User_) ->
      Account = _Account_
      User    = _User_
    )

    describe 'initialize', ->
      it 'should call new User', ->
        spyOn(window, 'User').and.callFake( (value) ->
          return value
        )
        account = new Account({ id: 1 })
```

I got always:
Error: User() method does not exist

Here a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxe05zg9/2/)

When I remove the spy the test is green and the console.log is called.
When I add the spyOn, I got the error.

How do I make a test to check if the new User is called?

Comment: You are asking Jasmine to spy on the `User` method of the `window` object: `spyOn(window, 'User')`.

Comment: I know no other way to spy new User, but window does not know User.

Comment: When you create the `Account`, you need to send in a *mock* `User`.

Comment: Sorry, I dont know how to do this

Comment: You must use `$provide` to create your factory. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773269/injecting-a-mock-into-an-angularjs-service

Comment: Yes, to use $provide with an factory.doSomething will be easy, but how do I this with 'new User'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to mock an Angular service (in JS, I do not speak CS):

```
describe('app', function() {
    describe('Account', function() {

        var Account, User;

        // This is always first
        beforeEach(module('app'));

        // This ***HAS*** to go before the beforeEach(inject(...)) block
        beforeEach(function() {
            User = ...; // mock it as necessary, e.g. jasmine.createSpy('UserMock')

            module(function($provide) {
                $provide.value('User', User);
            });
        });

        beforeEach(inject(function(_Account_) {
            Account = _Account_;
        }));

        // Now the User is mocked
        ...
    });
});
```

If the `User` is mocked with `jasmine.createSpy`, then the following fiddle demonstrates a successful test: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lveyb50/

Comment: Thx, but how do I check if User was called?

Comment: That depends on how are you planning to mock it.

Comment: Thx for the fiddle. One more problem for me. How do I call .callFake on this spy, created with createSpy.