# AngularJS combining web service responses

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have two web services:

One returns "Articles" like this:

```
[   
    {
        "id": "1",
        "headline": "some text",
        "body": "some text",
        "authorId": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "headline": "some text",
        "body": "some text",
        "authorId": "1"
    }
]
```

And the other one returns an "Author" like this, given an id:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Test Name",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "photo": "path/to/img"
}
```

I want to combine the two, so I can display the authors name and photo in an article overview list.

Like this:

```
[   
    {
        "id": "1",
        "headline": "some text",
        "body": "some text",
        "authorId": "2",
        "author_info": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Another Test Name",
            "email": "test2@test.com",
            "photo": "path/to/img"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "headline": "some text",
        "body": "some text",
        "authorId": "1"
        "author_info": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Test Name",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "photo": "path/to/img"
        }
    }
]
```

I have an "Articles" service that fetches the articles, but what's the best approach for enriching the returned JSON with the author info from the similar "Authors" service before returning the "Articles" service output?

```
factory('Authors', ['$http', function($http){
    var Authors = {

        data: {},

        get: function(id){
            return $http.get('/api/authors/' + id + '.json')
                .success(function(data) {
                    Authors.data = data;
                })
                .error(function() {
                    return {};
                });
        }
    };

    return Authors;
}]).

factory('Articles', ['$http', 'Authors', function($http, Authors){
    var Articles = {

        data: {},

        query: function(){
            return $http.get('/api/articles.json')
                .success(function(result) {
                    Articles.data = result; // How to get the author info into this JSON object???
                })
                .error(function() {
                    Articles.data = [];
                });
        }
    };
    return Articles;
}])
```

Please also tell me if this is an entirely wrong approach. :)

Answer (score 6):

When communicating with API, I would recommend the following approach to structuring your services (as [advised by Misko Hevery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11850027/1095616)):

```
    // Author model/service
    angular.module('myApp').factory('Author', function($http) {
      var Author = function(data) {
        angular.extend(this, data);
      };

      Author.get = function(id) {
        return $http.get('/authors/' + id).then(function(response) {
          return new Author(response.data);
        });
      };

      return Author;
    });

    // Article model/service
    angular.module('myApp').factory('Article', function($http) {
      var Article = function(data) {
        angular.extend(this, data);
      };

      Article.query = function() {
        return $http.get('/articles/').then(function(response) {
          var articles = [];
          angular.forEach(response.data, function(data){
            articles.push(new Article(data));
          });
          return articles;
        });
      };

      return Article;
    });

    // Your controller
    angular.module('myApp')
      .controller('Ctrl'
        ,[
          '$scope'
          ,'Article'
          ,'Author'
          ,function($scope, Article, Author){
            Article.query()
              .then(function(articles){
                $scope.articles = articles;
                attachAuthors(articles);
              });

            function attachAuthors(articles){
              angular.forEach(articles, function(article){
                Author.get(article.authorId)
                  .then(function(author){
                    article.author = author;
                  });
              });
            }

          }
        ]
      );
```

But for sure, I would also advise against fetching all this data in separate calls. Instead, if possible, you should have your API return you the combined JSON. Server-side combining would be many times faster.

Comment: Thanks for the advice + the link to Misko's answer. Very informative.

Answer (score 2):

Check out JSOG. It is perfect for doing this sort of stuff. There are currently server implementations for Java, Python, Javascript and Ruby. On the client javascript side, you just call JSOG.decode(object). I use it heavily with Angular.

https://github.com/jsog/jsog

Comment: Hey @jon-stevens, you said that you use jsog heavily with AngularJS, can you say how you do that?

Comment: @JayrMotta Thanks for asking! It is pretty simple, you just `decoded = JSOG.decode(data)`, where `data` is the body response from your ajax request. In the case of angular, I do this in the `.success()` promise for $http or within an interceptor.

Comment: I did this in order to work globally before the json text was derialized:

```javascript
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse.splice(0, 0, function(data, headersGetter) {
      if (data && headersGetter()['content-type'] === 'application/json') {
        return JSOG.parse(data);
      } else {
        return data;
      }
    });
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to combine all this data on the server, maybe creating a separate json file. This will simplify the client-side and require only one HTTP request instead of two.

If you are keeping both services (which is not a bad approach) you could fire one, wait for the answer and fire the second. Maybe do the `Articles` first and then the `Authors`:

```
Articles.get(function (articles) {                
            $scope.articles = articles;
            //fire query for Authors
            Authors.query(function (authors) {
              $scope.authors= authors;
              //combine both articles and authors
              combineData(articles, authors);                    
           }) 
});
```

Here is the function that **combines the data**:

```
function combineData(articles, authors){
  $.each(articles, function (i, article) {
      //find author
      var author = $.grep(authors, function(a, j){
                     return a.id == article.authorId;
                   });
      //set article's author
      article.author_info = author;
    });
}
```

Notice that with this configuration your articles will render (by setting `$scope.articles`) even before making the call to `Authors.query`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this would mean fetching all authors on every article, right? That's a lot of traffic.

Comment: No, the code assumes you can fetch all Articles and upon completion you would fetch ALL Authors. Then combine the results. Only two requests are involved

Comment: @JakobLøkkeMadsen did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes. We opted for merging data on the server and do fewer ajax-calls.