# Idiomatic way to share data between controllers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know that there are plenty of ways to share data between controllers in Angular.
e.g. snooping prototypical data from parent scope, notifying controllers by scope events, shared services etc.

But what is the idiomatic way to share data for all controllers in a view?

I've read this post: [Share data between controllers in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445725/share-data-between-controllers-in-angularjs)

Is this the way to go? resolve loaded data upfront and then share the result?

Comment: What do you mean by all controllers in a view? What do you mean by view? It sounds like you're looking for a service though

Answer (score 0):

You can write directives contain controller inside and isolated scope with two-way binding variable that you want to share

js:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('main',['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.sharedVar = 1;
  }]);
  app.directive('dOne', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        sharedVar: '='
      },
      controller: ['$scope',function($scope) {
        $scope.changeVar = function(val) {
          $scope.sharedVar = val;
        }
      }],
      template: "<div>controller1<button ng-click='changeVar(3)'>clickMe!</button> value: {{sharedVar}}</div>"
    };
  });

  app.directive('dTwo', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        sharedVar: '='
      },
      controller: ['$scope',function($scope) {
        $scope.changeVar = function(val) {
          $scope.sharedVar = val;
        }
      }],
      template: "<div>controller2<button ng-click='changeVar(2)'>clickMe!</button> value: {{sharedVar}}</div>"
    };
  });
})();
```

html

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='main'>
    <d-one shared-var="sharedVar"></d-one>
    <d-two shared-var="sharedVar"></d-two>
  </body>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kNSi9QnIi9wroAT4WAzT?p=preview)

another option is to use $parent scope
[plunker using $parent scope](http://plnkr.co/edit/2hnuvCwIoIXV9rlrNamD?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `resolve` on my router, so initial values are resolved upfront and then readily available for all controllers.