# AngularJs $resource dynamic URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, ldap

I have this REST service, which speaks with LDAP server. In order to get all available data about user, I must visit this:

```
GET /users/:userId
```

Because user in LDAP is described by attributes, I want to get only some not all attributes. In this case must do this:

```
GET /users/:userId/o/mail/displayName/....(list of attributes required)
```

How to create this dynamic url for attribute list while using AngularJS $resource?

```
.factory('User', ['$resource', 'REST_API_URL', function ($resource, REST_API_URL) {
    var User = $resource(
                REST_API_URL + '/users/:id', 
                {id: '@id'}
        );

    return User;
}])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first URL you describe follows RESTful convention, but not the second one. When there are actions verbs (here displayName) in URIs, your API is no longer RESTful.

[AngularJS $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) interacts with RESTful server-side data sources only. Your API must follow a lot of RESTful conventions.

I recommend you [read answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003092/whats-the-angularjs-way-of-handling-a-crud-resource) which is highly related and describe those conventions.

As your API does not meet these criteria you will have to build your own $resource-like CRUD service based on the lower-level [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850025/recommended-way-of-getting-data-from-the-server/11850027#11850027))

Comment: You can anyway override resource methods to specify custom Url:

var Order = $resource('myUrl/:orderId', {orderId : "@orderId"}, 

        {
            query:{
                method : 'GET',
                isArray : false,
                url: 'myCustomUrl',
            }
        }

    );