# rest request ending by "/" works on chrome, not firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, rest, firefox

I am using Angularjs Chrome 35.0 and Firefox 30.0.
I need to make  Rest requests to an API.
Some of those finishes by `/` like : `http://mydomain.com/path/to/folder/`

It won't work without this / and I don't have the hand on the API.

To do this I use un service using resource :

```
this.folder = function(folderKey) {
        var methods = resource(url, null, {
            'create': {
                method: 'PUT',
                url: config.domain + folderPath + '\\/'
            }
        });
        return methods;
    };
```

If I only put `/` or `\/`, angular doesn't keep the ending `/` while doing the request.

The    `'\\/'` is the only way i found to keep it.

It does work well in chrome but in firefox it does make this url which obviously doesn't work : `http://mydomain.com/path/to/folder%5C`

Comment: The code here contains a range of syntax errors. Can you show some code which actually illustrates what you are doing to make the request?

Comment: @chrisg : I forgot one line of code, added it.

Comment: That looks better thanks. It is a little strange that the server is that sensitive to having a trailing `/` on the URL, but I guess you can't change that. Does it help to put a `/.` on the end of the URL? I wonder whether that would make the browser send through what you need, and whether the server will handle that to do the create action as desired.

Comment: what happens when trailing `/` left off at API? Seems unusual to need one. If you control the API would be simpler to fix at server if it is causing problems

Comment: It won't work without this `/` and I don't have the hand on the API.

Comment: @chrisg : with a `.` at the end, firefox sends : `http://mydomain.com/path/to/folder%5C\` and so it work with 
`url: config.domain + folderPath + '\/.'`.

Comment: Apparently it also work with chrome !

Comment: @chrisg, you can post the answer I will accept it, it does work well.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to

[Recommended way of getting data from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850025/recommended-way-of-getting-data-from-the-server/11850027#comment15909222_11850027)

it seems that people recommend the use of $http instead of ressource for that kind of url.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a `.` at the end of the URL will avoid the trailing `\` from being trimmed. Whether this will work in general will obviously depend on how the server handles the `.`, but if you have a server that does what you want then it should help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above that the web service should not be sensitive to the trailing slash in url.

But if you really want to turn off the auto stripTrailingSlashes behaviour, you can pass the option like this:

```
this.folder = function(folderKey) {
    var methods = resource(url, null, {
        'create': {
            method: 'PUT',
            url: config.domain + folderPath + '\\/'
        }
    }, {
        stripTrailingSlashes: false
    });
    return methods;
};
```

**Edit:** this feature is available since angular v1.3.0-beta.6 which is still in an unstable state.

Comment: This doesn't change anything.

Comment: Neither with `'\\/'`, with `'\/'` and `'/'`

Comment: What is your angular.js version?

Comment: I see, this option is available since v1.3.0-beta.6, not in the stable versions yet.

Comment: True, according to : 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3878be52f6d95fca4c386d4a5523f3c8fcb04270