# How Angular SPA relates to REST API

Tags: angularjs, rest, express, single-page-application

I'm newbie in node and I'm trying to understand how an Angular SPA, that have some states with uiRouter, can relates to an Express REST API to get data from an database. Can anyone please take me an exemple?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AugularJS SPA can talk to REST API through a variety of modules like [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)  or a more *complete* library like [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)

### Example with $resource

For example if your Express API can `GET` a user on `/user/<userId>`, and save it back through a `POST`, you can do this on AngularJS

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save();
});
```

To understand what $resource will do on HTTP on each action refer to this default mapping

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

### $http is low level (and built-upon by the REST client libraries)

Another answer here suggested `$http`. While it's entirely possible to do so, the REST libraries already build upon `$http`, to give you convenient  support for the HTTP verbs and general REST facilities.

If you use `$http` you'll have to do that manually (not to mention you won't be benefiting from the wisdom and best practices that went into building those libraries)

Answer (score 1):

I won't recommend to use `$resource`. It's the object that keeps link to the promise and when promise resolved it'll also contain data itself. So if you want to do some actions when data comes you'll have to assing a callback to that promise anyway. Use `$http` instead. It's lower level angular abstraction for async requests. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850025/recommended-way-of-getting-data-from-the-server) is the way you can use `$http`.